# How to scale out screen size on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I use Win 10 with scaling 100%...

[image]

My monitor is LCD Lenovo.
I feel that the LCD display is so big. Maybe larger than 15"
I like to scale out my screen size maybe 80% or 70%

I can do this on Win 7, but I can not do it in Win 10.

I need a suggestion what program/application is needed to scale out my screen size at 80%

Comment: You are at 1360x768...are you sure that is your native resolution? A lower resolution  than optimal will feel like the text is "too big".

Comment: you can't do that. [How to scale windows below 100%](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/832222-how-to-scale-windows-below-100/), [Is custom scaling below 100% possible in Windows 10?](https://windowsreport.com/custom-scaling-windows-10-below-100/), [Scaling screen to less than 100%](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/scaling-screen-to-less-than-100/b47b6010-beb4-45a3-bb88-652f2d7c2f1f)

Comment: @phuclv yes but the solution does not work

Comment: of course it doesn't work because Windows 10 doesn't allow you to do that as I commented above